# Remove padding, align text to top of div

Tags: html, css

Im currently creating a print css! Because i have to print on a template i use mm as unit!

My problem is how you can see that the red text is not aligned to the top of the white box, it seems like the white box has a padding! I would like to have the text exactly 1 mm below the red line. I tried to give the text a `margin-top:1mm` but the text stayed at the position! http://jsfiddle.net/WkhPb  I would like to keep mm as unit what do i have to change? Thanks

[image]

My html:

```
<div id="box">
 <div id="adress">
  <a>Das ist Box 1</a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
#box{
   height:40mm;
   width:90mm;
   background-color:yellow;
   padding-left: 6mm;
   padding-right: 5mm;
   padding-top: 2mm;
}

#adress {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 30mm;
    height: 20mm;
    background-color: white;
}

#adress a {
    color: red;
    font-size: 2mm;
    margin-left: 1mm;
    margin-top: 0mm;
    line-height: 0mm;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WkhPb/

Comment: Is it ok ? http://jsfiddle.net/WkhPb/3/

Comment: try this in #adress: 

padding: 0px;

Comment: Yes thanks! Yould you please a answer? So that i can mark it as correct?

Comment: Do you want the text inside or outside the box? You're getting a mix of answers

Comment: So you want the **"text exactly 1mm below the red line"**? If so I'll amend your question to stop the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `position : absolute` on your link

http://jsfiddle.net/WkhPb/3/

```
#adress a {
    color: red;
    font-size: 2mm;
    position:absolute;
    top:1mm;
    left:1mm;
}
```

and `position:relative` on the parent

Comment: Am not interested in arguing. Just deleted my answer. In css, there can be many ways to achieve a slution. isnt?

Comment: sure ... why do you say that to me ?

Comment: This is not ideal. All he wants to do is remove padding, no need to over-complicate it with something that could have adverse effects on other parts later.

Comment: I agree but in that case he should have told us more, with the only information I've got, this is the solution

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a line-height of 3mm on the containing div to match your font and give it the 1mm margin from the top you require. You probably would want to put a padding on the sides of the div as well so the text doesn't sit right on it.

```
#adress {
    line-height:3mm;
    padding:0 1mm;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the padding and margin that is applied by the browser and set it to 0;

Secondly You must set the display property of the link to block or inline-block to be able to apply margin.

```
*{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
 }


#address a{
 display:block;
}
```

**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nathvarun/WkhPb/5/)**

Answer (score 1):

You said: "I would like to have the text exactly 1 mm **above** the red line.."

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WkhPb/6/)

change your css to this:

```
#adress a {
        color: red;
        font-size: 2mm;
        margin-left: 1mm;
        margin-top: -2mm; /* changed */
        line-height: 0mm;
        display:block;  /* added */
    }
```

Comment: I think he worded it wrong and wants it inside the box

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
padding: 0px;
```

Inside #adress.

Comment: This removes any default padding on the element.

Comment: Can I ask, why is the link inside the box, when you want it to display outside of it? Why not have the link outside the box like you want it to be displayed?